# Codeigniter Session Outside the application folder

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to get session outside codeigniter application folder?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to get session inside a php file outside the application folder.

Comment: You could always try it and see if it will work. I'm sure it won't though. Why don't you just convert the php file outside your project to part of your CI project?

Comment: I want to dynamically load a 'theme.php' css file based on the user session.

Comment: You can definitely do this in a CI project. No need to have php code outside your project.

Comment: theme.php would not be a css file either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but not without some work. You can see the details of someone else's problem and their [solution in the CodeIgniter forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/86380/#435269).

Basically you need take the cookie that CodeIgniter uses to handle it's sessions and unserialize it:

```
$sess = unserialize($_COOKIE['ci_session']);
```

You may need to also change settings in your application so that cookies are set for the entire domain, not just for the folder that CodeIgniter sits in.

Comment: Thanks. So I want to write my details to cookie and get it using unserialize cookie. Is it persistent cookie or not?

Comment: There is a configuration setting in CodeIgniter to specify the length of the cookies yo set, right at the bottom of this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html Also, there is actually a cookie helper class http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html not sure when this was introduced as I've never come across it before, but might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Its a trick but do work. Place this little naughty code just before login redirect. And now you can use `ci_session` with php native session too ,have fun !

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['ci_session'] = $this->session->userdata['ci_session'];
 ?>
```